# I'm using CiviContribute and need CAPTCHA

Tags: security, payment-gateways, civicrm

I'm new to Drupal and CiviCRM. I work mostly with Blackbaud/NetCommunity. I'm operating a website that using CiviContribute for donations. Our Payment Processor is Paypal Payments Pro.

I'm trying to add in a CAPTCHA or verification method to our donation part. I can't find how to add a CAPTCHA or any verification to the donation form. I don't see any customizable options on the payment page.

Is it possible to add a CAPTCHA on a CiviContribute donation form?

Comment: lol, don't be silly, I've never seen a CAPTCHA in a payment form. The paypal API has a verification method, not sure if the CiviCRM module uses it, but one would think they would.

Comment: This isn't an absurd request. There a few bot tools that might hammer a payment form (e.g. bulk verifying stolen CC #'s, looking for common security holes, etc.)

Comment: certainly true that payment pages do get hammered by people/machines testing stolen card details.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be asking this on the CiviCRM stack.

You can set a catpcha on a Profile. So check which Profiles you have set for the Contribution page. Then edit the Advanced settings for that Profile where you can set captcha.

Check answer [here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7018/how-to-add-captcha-on-civicrm-contribution-pages-and-events-pages) too

Comment: cool. it helps stackexchange if you can +1 any answer that is useful, and tick (accept) the answer that best answers - this helps everyone